# Can I disable the internal speakers while keeping the audio jack enabled?

Tags: sound, kernel, mac, macbook-pro

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on my MacBook Pro 4,1 and it is working great. The only problem is that my broken speakers let out static all the time. I somehow broke the speakers while I was repasting the heatsinks a while back, and it isn't a big deal in OS X or Windows 7 because I can easily turn off the internal speakers by muting or plugging in headphones. The same doesn't work in Ubuntu, and the constant static had me so annoyed that I have added the snd_hda_intel and snd_hda_codec_realtek kernel modules to the blacklist to completely disable sound. Does anyone have a solution that will let me still use my headphones for music, just not the internal speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `alsamixer` in terminal and see if you can mute it by pressing `m`.

**Another possible solution:**

A more involved possible work around. Type `lspci` in your terminal

Look for the audio controller responsible for sound. Find the PCI location of the device.

I was unable to edit these pci device without using `su`

`echo -n "0000:00:1b.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/"YOUR SOUND CONTROLLER"/unbind`

"YOUR SOUND CONTROLLER" in my case was "snd_hda_intel" and "0000:00:1b.0" was my pci location. To rebind,

`echo -n "0000:00:1b.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/"YOUR SOUND CONTROLLER"/bind`

Does it work? If so, then make a script that you can run that will enable/disable that pci location.

**Another solution:**

The idea is to keep the headphone jack permanently on, or to disable the internal speakers via pulseaudio. The documentation is not very easy to read but the location of these files are in

`/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common`

or

`/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`

Comment: I tried that before I blacklisted the modules, and it didn't work

Comment: Let me know how my update goes.

Comment: should this do something immediately? Did you mean "enable"? I don't have a text file called "enabled", but I change the 1 in enable to a 0 and saved; nothing happened.

Comment: Derp, I gave you old information. In 14.04, it is "enabled" which isn't relevant to us anymore. Check out the edit again and let me know.

Comment: lspci gave me the same pci device and controller as you, so I just did sudo su, then pasted your unbind line. No change. When I did it with bind, I got a little blip in the static output but that is all.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Seems like this solution is only a software solution. What we want to do is disable power to your speakers and I guess unbinding it does not cut the power, it only unmounts it. In the older kernels, you used to be able to have it power off, but the only options now are auto and on.

Comment: I fixed it, kinda. I ended up blacklisting the snd_hda_codec_realtek module, and messing around with alsa force-reload. The internal speakers are off now, and the audio jack works, but it is really quiet.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I came up with another idea, but I haven't worked the details out yet. I'll give you the concept in the edit. Glad to have helped.

Comment: "echo -n "0000:00:1b.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/snd_hda_intel/unbind"

in /etc/rc.local worked like a charm (Linux on Macbook Air)

Thx