# How to automatically mute on headphones disconnect? Or how to tap bash script to system event listener?

Tags: sound, bash, scripts, headphones, events

My life would be easier if Ubuntu was muting the `sound` each time I disconnect the `headphones`, since every time surrounding is different (example day / night), but the same output volume.

I may figure out the script for that but not without interaction with `Ubuntu event listener`. I know nothing about it so far.

I will appreciate solution or tip for either subject, but rather not installation of any `package` for so simple thing, bunch of these is making `update` way too long + I like my system to be possibly clean or reasoned.

---

Actually I would write a lot more solutions I'm missing with the knowledge of `reaction to events`, like auto-adjusting USB mouse settings on connect (the hell they reset for?) or auto enabling GSM modem on connect.

Comment: If you mute sounds **before** connecting the headphones, it will be mute **after** disconnecting them too.

Comment: Thanks for Your comment, I noticed that but perceive not as an automatic solution.

Answer (score 7):

First of, open `alsamixer` program in terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T).

[image]

Check if automute is Enabled. You can navigate to it by using left-right keys, and up down to toggle the value. Esc to exit.

Now, if you mute sound without headphones , plug the headphones, and unplug them again, sound through speakers should stay muted. At least on my machine, with Auto-Mute enabled, I can keep speakers muted, while headphones can output sound upon plugging in.

Comment: Thanks... I'm seeing only `S/PDIF` column. Your last paragraph's solution works so far but is not automatic. I want `speakers` to be always muted after `headphones` disconnection, dependless on previous setting.

Comment: You may want to refer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/437924/295286) post. I've thought also of another alternative - there are usb sound cards , where you plug-in headphones. You could blacklist your internal sound-card, and only use usb sound card, with headphones , to completely disable internal speakers. (I have one myself, because on my other laptop internal sound card is dead completely, and i can only get sound this way)

Comment: If you see only s/pdif in alsamixer, press F6 and select another soundcard than the default (usually HDMI output)

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

1. To see notifications you have to install notify-osd `sudo apt install notify-osd`
2. Create a text file `<my_name>.sh` in your `/home/<user_name>/` directory. And add execute permission to the file `chmod +x /home/<user_name>/<my_name>.sh`
3. Paste the text below to the `<my_name>.sh` file

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r line;
   do
       if [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" ]
       then
          amixer -D pulse set Master mute
          notify-send "headphones connected. Sound is muted"
       elif [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug" ]
       then
          amixer -D pulse set Master mute
          notify-send "headphones disconnected.  Sound is muted"
       fi
   done
   ```
4. Go to **Startup Configurations** menu of your linux system (ubuntu, kubuntu, xubuntu etc). Set `/home/<user_name>/<my_name>.sh` file to **autostart** **with** you desktop environment (xfce, KDE, Gnome etc).

**Warning!** If you use KDE then **DON NOT** add the file for `"Start script before KDE"` or `"Application"` with `bash /home/<user_name>/<my_name>.sh`.
Use **as script** (scenario) and **"Start WITH KDE"**.
**IF** you did that already then press `ctrl + alt + F2`, login as user and delete `rm /home/<user_name>/<my_name>.sh`. If you don't have permissions to delete then remount your disk before deleting `mount -o remount, rw /`.

#### How to edit the script

Some linux based systems **cache** autostart scripts. That means even if you edit `/home/<user_name>/<my_name>.sh` and `logout / login` or `restart` the system then the script will stay the same.
In KDE you can find the cached script symbolic link in `/home/<user_name>/.config/autostart-scripts/<my_name>.sh`. Delete the `<my_name>.sh` file manually, `logout / login` system, add the script to `autostart` again and `logout / login` again.
It seems to me it's **KDE bug**. I don't know about other DE (xfce, Gnome etc)

#### What you need to know

You can see text as `"jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug"` in the code above. It's the headphones event name.

**To see events:**
1. Type in the console `acpi_listen`
2. **Plug** and **unplug** headphones (or another devices)
3. You will see event names in the **console**. It'll be something like a text below

```
    user@user-PC:~$ acpi_listen
    jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug
    jack/microphone MICROPHONE unplug
    jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug
    jack/microphone MICROPHONE plug
```

If event names in the script above **are different** then replace them by your event names from the **console** output.

#### ACPI and events

To see and test ACPI events you can use **evtest**
`sudo apt install evtest`

```
    user@user-PC:~$ sudo evtest
    No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
    Available devices:
    /dev/input/event0:      Lid Switch
    /dev/input/event1:      Power Button
    /dev/input/event2:      Power Button
    /dev/input/event3:      AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
    /dev/input/event4:      Video Bus
    /dev/input/event5:      SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
    /dev/input/event6:      COMPANY USB Device
    /dev/input/event7:      COMPANY USB Device
    /dev/input/event8:      COMPANY USB Device
    /dev/input/event9:      HP Wireless hotkeys
    /dev/input/event10:     HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
    /dev/input/event11:     HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
    /dev/input/event12:     HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
    /dev/input/event13:     HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9
    /dev/input/event14:     HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10
    /dev/input/event15:     HDA Intel PCH Mic
    /dev/input/event16:     HDA Intel PCH Headphone
    /dev/input/event17:     HP WMI hotkeys
    /dev/input/event18:     HP Webcam: HP Webcam
    Select the device event number [0-18]: 16
    Input driver version is 1.0.1
    Input device ID: bus 0x0 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
    Input device name: "HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
    Supported events:
    Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
    Event type 5 (EV_SW)
        Event code 2 (SW_HEADPHONE_INSERT) state 1
    Properties:
    Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
    Event: time 1522588668.319567, type 5 (EV_SW), code 2 (SW_HEADPHONE_INSERT), value 0
    Event: time 1522588668.319567, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------                      
    Event: time 1522588670.035275, type 5 (EV_SW), code 2 (SW_HEADPHONE_INSERT), value 1       
    Event: time 1522588670.035275, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

For some reasons `/etc/acpi/events/jack` does not work for me. Possibly I have wrong **CONFIG_SND_HDA_INPUT_JACK** option. To test that use

```
    sudo grep CONFIG_SND_HDA_INPUT_JACK /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

My answer is based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/879185/813587) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can automate this by setting an ACPI listener for headphone plug/unplug events:

```
$ grep headphone /etc/acpi/handler.sh -A 11                                                                                                         
    jack/headphone)                                                                                                                                 
        case "$3" in
            plug)
                logger "Headphones plugged"
                amixer sset 'Headphone' 30%
                ;;
            unplug)
                logger "Headphones unplugged"
                amixer sset 'Speaker' 30%
                ;;
    esac
    ;;
$ systemctl restart acpid
```

**Another way:**
Instead of modifying `/etc/acpi/handler.sh` you can create another config file in `/etc/acpi/events/` and specify your own script to handle these events. Use the default configuration as a template:

```
$ cat /etc/acpi/events/anything                                                                                                                     
# Pass all events to our one handler script                                                                                                         
event=.*
action=/etc/acpi/handler.sh %e
```

Look at `man acpid` for more details.